# As chaves em um nó de uma B-tree estão em ordem não-decrescente ou crescente?

Tags: estrutura-de-dados, árvore

O CRLS (Introduction to the Algorithms, Cormen et al) define que as chaves de um nó em uma B-tree devem estar em ordem não-decrescente (K1 <= K2 <= ... <= Kn). No entanto, como não há repetição de chaves, esta ordem deveria ser estritamente crescente (assim, também, afirmam Bayer e McGreight, no seu artigo de 1972). Isto está correto?

Answer (score 1):

A B-tree é um tipo de generalização da árvore binária, onde os nós são agrupados em páginas e cada uma delas pode apontar para várias outras. Suas propriedades a fazem ideal para trabalhar com discos, pois minimiza as operações mais custosas (girar o disco e mover o cabeçote, ou seja, iniciar a leitura de um bloco).

Quando Bayer e McGreight escreveram seu artigo eles não estavam interessados em que tipos de dados seriam armazenados por estas árvores. O objetivo era definir a árvore teoricamente, mostrar tempos de acesso, escrita e deleção e apresentar os cálculos e algoritmos importantes. Mas depois de 1972 ela começou a ser utilizada e com o passar dos anos o termo foi sendo aplicado um pouco fora da definição original.

As B-trees são muito utilizadas em bancos de dados e outras formas de guardar grandes quantidades de dados em um disco. Em algumas circunstâncias ter chaves repetidas pode ser uma vantagem, já que o tempo para eliminá-las pode ser muito alto. Porém isso causa diversos problemas, principalmente na deleção.

Imagine que uma mesma chave se repita várias vezes e se deseje deletar um dos elementos que foi armazenado com aquela chave. Vai ser preciso andar por todas as ocorrências daquela chave até achar o elemento específico, o que será bem ineficiente.

Geralmente quando uma B-tree contém chaves repetidas é adicionado mais um atributo para fazer uma chave composta de modo que ela seja única. Assim, algumas operações podem utilizar a chave normal e outras a chave composta. Outra solução é manter um índice separado que gerencia todas as chaves repetidas.

Enfim, no artigo era melhor considerar que as chaves são únicas, pois assim toda a teoria iria ficar mais elegante, tratar casos de chaves repetidas não seria interessante. Mas na prática existem casos em que é melhor usar uma B-tree com chaves não únicas permitidas e solucionar os problemas resultantes de outras maneiras. Nem por isso as pessoas vão deixar de chamar de B-tree.

Logo o livro do Cormem preferiu definir a B-tree dessa forma, para não excluir esses casos onde a chave não é única e que podem ser usados na prática.